# setTimeout - Is there a correct way to implement it?

Tags: javascript

This is my piece of code in an .aspx file

```
<script>
 setTimeout(redirect(), 35000);
 function redirect()
 {
    window.location.href = "ReportCard.aspx?TestTransID=<%=testtransid %>";
 }
</script>
```

I expect the settimeout to execute the redirect function after 35 seconds, but the moment this page is loaded it redirects the page immediately. it doesnot wait for 35 seconds.

Have I missed anything ?

Comment: `setTimeout(redirect, 35000);`

Comment: What you missed is that adding the () after the function name in setTimeout causes the function to be called immediately.  Jared has the correct answer above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are invoking the function using `()`. You need to either wrap it into function like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  redirect()
}, 35000);
```

Or, simply assign the reference to the function like:

```
setTimeout(redirect, 35000);
```

Comment: thank you. that worked.